# Sass: Using HSLa Fallback Technique

Tags: css, sass, hsl

Does anyone know a workaround for enabling HSLa color declarations in SASS-compiled stylesheets?

I'd like to use HSLa for the reasons discussed in this [article](http://css-tricks.com/yay-for-hsla/) by Chris Coyier. The fallback technique recommended in the [Modernizr Docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css) is to declare a hex value first followed by the HSLa value for supporting browsers.

However, the way Sass currently implements its [hsla() instance method](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#hsla-instance_method) makes it impossible to use this technique -- all HSLa values are compiled to hex, which means the hex color just gets repeated.

I've tried defining the Sass color variable as a string, but that compiles to a quoted string in the stylesheet.

Can anyone suggest a hack for getting HSLa output using Sass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it into a string and then unquote it.  This will prevent the Sass hsla() function from being called:

```
.test {
    background-color: #e2ecf0; /* Fallback */
    background-color: unquote("hsla(190, 30%, 94%, 1)"); 
}
```

Generates:

```
.test {
  background-color: #e2ecf0;
  /* Fallback */
  background-color: hsla(190, 30%, 94%, 1);
}
```

Comment: That's awesome - hadn't seen unquote() before, that's likely to be a very handy tool. Thanks very much

Comment: But the advantages of hsla (as expressed in the article) are how much sense it makes as a designer. I use it all the time in Sass, for that very reason. But if the advantage is on your end, and Sass allows that, and the output already works in all browsers without any negative effect, why do you care that it's hex/rgba output? The standard Sass output is actually *cleaner* than having a fallback. Why use a fallback when you can just use the real thing and have Sass make the conversion for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use interpolation (`#{}`) and quotes:

```
.test {
    background-color: #e2ecf0; // Fallback
    background-color: #{"hsla(190, 30%, 94%, 1)"}; 
}
```